# A not Banach space

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

Please,  how to choose a sequence to prove that this space is not a Banach space $(\mathcal{C}([0,\frac12],\mathbb{R}),||.||_1)$.

In the exercice they present this sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac1n\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

but this sequence  is Cauchy and it converge to 0, so i can't use it to deduce that this space is not Banach!

Comment: What is the norm $||\cdot||_1$?

Comment: $\int_0^{1/2}|f(x)|dx$

Comment: The text likely has a typo, but if so, I dk what $f_n$ was supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Defined $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that:

- $f_n(x)=0$ if $x<\frac14-\frac1{4n}$;
- $f_n(x)=1$ if $x>\frac14+\frac1{4n}$;
- $f_n$ is affine on $\left[\frac14-\frac1{4n},\frac14+\frac1{4n}\right]$.

Then $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, but it doesn't converge on $\mathcal C\left(\left[0,\frac12\right]\right)$.

Comment: is there a way to use the given function in the exercice ?

Comment: I dont't think so. No example of the type $f_n(x)=\frac1nf(x)$will work.